# babel 6 and constants folding / propagation

Tags: babeljs, constantfolding

Could someone suggest the right way to eliminate constants from the code in production mode? I've already tested *babel-plugin-constant-folding* and *babel-plugin-dead-code-elimination* but they both work only with babel 5, not with babel 6.

Example:

```
const K=1;
const B=K + 13;
console.log("b=" + B);
```

I expect to get:

```
console.log("k=" + 1 + ", b=" + 14)
```

or, better (honestly, I don't need this level of optimization, replacing all ID with their values without string concat is completely enough for me):

```
console.log("k=1, b=13")
```

but get only:

```
var K = 1,
    B = K + 13;
console.log("k=" + K + ", b=" + B);
```

Could someone suggest me the right sequence of babel plugins?